# Analyzing logical form of "x is the smallest number that is a multiple of both y and z."

Tags: logic

Statement:

> x is the smallest number that is a multiple of both y and z. Universe of discourse is $ℕ$.

My attempt (all variables declared below are in domain $ℕ$):
$$\exists a(y=xa) \land \exists b( z=xb) \land \forall p\bigr(p \in [0,x-1] \rightarrow (\lnot \exists a(y=pa) \land \lnot \exists b(z=pb))\bigl)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: $x$ is multiple of $y$ means $x=ay$.

Comment: $p \in [0, x-1]$ is not first-order logic.

Comment: So $p<x$ is the only correct way to express that p is smaller than x?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It is shorthand for something which is first-order logic, so it is first-order logic.

Comment: @Nelver Be careful with $0$. It is a multiple of anything, and smaller than anything. So if $0$ is in $\Bbb N$, you have to specify that $x$ and $p$ are non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line doesn't say what you want it to say.

What you are trying to say is

> $x$ is a multiple of both $y$ and $z$, and any number less than $x$ is not a multiple of both $y$ and $z$.

However, you have not negated "is a multiple of both $y$ and $z$" correctly. What your attempt says is

> $x$ is a multiple of both $y$ and $z$, and any number less than $x$ is not a multiple of $y$ and it's not a multiple of $z$.

I would personally prefer to write it a bit differently:

> $x$ is a multiple of both $y$ and $z$, and any number that is a multiple of both $y$ and $z$ is greater than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Is this version correct? $∃(=)∧∃(=)∧∀(<→(¬∃(=)∨¬∃(=)))$

Comment: @Nelver Yes, with the "or" instead of the "and", it is now correct. I would prefer to change $\lnot\exists a$ into $\forall a\lnot$, but that's just an aesthetic concern.

Comment: @Nelver I would recommend formulating the positive form of formula suggested by Arthur's last description.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct.  The last clause says $x$ is neither a multiple of $y$ nor a multiple of $z$.  Let $y=2,z=4$.  The correct $x$ is $4$, but $2$ fails the last conjunct because it is a multiple of $y$.

Comment: I misunderstood what "multiple of" means. Revised version $∃(x=ya)∧∃(x=z)∧∀(<x→(¬∃(p=y)∧¬∃(p=z)))$ . Is it correct?

Comment: No, you have not addressed my concern.  You have to say that $p$ is not a multiple of at least one of $y,z$, while you are requiring that it be a multiple of neither.

Comment: Attempt number 3: $∃(=)∧∃(=)∧∀(<→(¬∃(=)\lor¬∃(=)))$

Answer (score 0):

$y\mid x \wedge z\mid x\wedge (\forall a: y\mid a\wedge z\mid a \wedge a\leq x \Rightarrow a= x)$.